# QThread::wait() and QThread::finished()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Does QThread::wait() return (i.e., unblocks execution) after calling all the slots that were associated with QThread::finished() signal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it may return before, during or after a slot associated with signal `finished()` is being executed.

This depends on the type of signal-slot connection, read about [queued connections and direct connections](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).